# To get the words that are having the particular special character as its last letter

Tags: javascript, dom-events, javascript-framework

My Code:

I tried the following code

```
var str = "Have fun storming the castle!"
var character = "!";

function endsWith(str, character) {
    return str.indexOf(character, str.length - character.length) !== -1;
}

alert(endsWith(str, character));
```

It is giving the result as `True` since such word is present in the sentence.

But I need the result as `castle!` as it is the only word having such character atlast. If multiple words having such character also, I need those words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function below takes the string and character, and returns an array of words that have the character as their last character. It is case sensitive but if you wanted to make it case insensitive then just add `.toLowerCase()` to the comparison line.

```
function getWords(str, character)
{
    var words = str.split(" ");
    var result = [];

    for(var i=0; i<words.length; i++)
    {
        if(words[i].slice(-1) == character)
        {
            result.push(words[i]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

var str = "Have fun storming the castle!";
var character = "!";

console.log( getWords(str, character) );
```

Outputs

> ["castle!"]

Multiple words test:

```
console.log( getWords("Have fun storming! the castle!", "!") );
```

Outputs

> ["storming!", "castle!"]

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d923v/)**

Comment: I tried the above function but it returns null because it not even enters the if condition since it is comparing the first character of each word to the character.

Comment: @universal I think you are mistaken. This works because substr(-1, 1) returns the last character of the word, not the first.

Comment: @universal take a look at the jsFiddle demo to show it working (I changed to a for loop to fix an issue with chrome). It's working in IE Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Thanks very much. Working fine as expected. I am using chrome.

Comment: In `IE` it is alerting without any result. I changed a little as follow to work in `IE` `for(var i in words)
    {
        if(words[i].match("!"))
        {
   if(character === words[i].charAt(words[i].length - 1))
    result.push(words[i]);
        }
    }`

Comment: @universal it works in IE for me, you shouldn't be alerting arrays, use console.log or alert the array element like something[0];

Comment: I used `alert(getWords(str, character));` like this. I am getting `Castle!` in `Firefox`, `Chrome`. But in `IE` no value is displayed. From `Notepad++`, I am working on.

Comment: That's what I mean, the problem is likely that you are trying to alert an array. What version of IE? Works fine in my IE9

Comment: I am also using `IE 9`. Full version number is `IE 9.0.8112.16421`

Comment: I've changed the `substr()` to `slice()` which I think is a little more elegant.

Comment: Yes. Now it is working fine with `slice()`. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "Have fun storming! the castle!"
var character = "!";

function getWords(str, character)
{
     var words = str.split(" ");
     var result = [];

     for(var i in words)
     {
         //if(words[i].search(character)!="-1")
         if(words[i].substring(words[i].length-1)==character)
         {
             result.push(words[i]);
         }
     }

     return result;
}

alert(getWords(str, character));
```

If string is "Have fun storming the castle!". Then it returns

**castle!**

and if string is "Have fun storming! the castle!". Then it returns
**storming!, castle!**

Comment: I want the result when that special character is atlast of the word. Your code gives the words even if the special character is in the middle.

Comment: I have just edited my code. You can see the changed -if loop-.This will give you what is required.

Comment: `+1` Yes, it is working fine as expected. Also, `if(character === words[i].charAt(words[i].length - 1))` will gives us the expected result. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use regular expressions. If you define it as "global", it will give you all matches in a list:

```
function endsWith (str, character) {
    regexp = new RegExp ('\\b.*?' + character + '\\b', 'g');
    return str.match (regexp);
}
```

However, to make it really nice, you should make sure character is escaped so it cannot mess up your regular expression:

```
function escape (character) {
    int num = character.charCodeAt (0);
    String code = '000' + num.toString (16);
    return '\\u' + code.substring (code.length - 4);
}

function endsWith (str, character) {
    regexp = new RegExp ('\\b.*?' + escape (character) + '\\b', 'g');
    return str.match (regexp);
}
```